# Error function ST_MapAlbebraExpr

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql

I'm trying to calculate a NDVI index for a raster of Landsat TM with ST_MapAlgebraExpr in PostGIS (2.1):

```
CREATE TABLE ndvi_lugo_tm AS (
SELECT
ST_MapAlgebraExpr(lugo_tm.rast, 5, lugo_tm.rast, 4, 
(('[rast1.val]-[rast2.val])/[rast1.val]+[rast2.val]+0.01')),
'32BF', 'INTERSECTION') 
AS rast, 1 AS rid
FROM lugo_tm AS lugo_tm);
```

But I get error:

**ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «)»
LINE 1: SELECT ($1-$2)/$1+$2+0.01)::double precision
                                 ^
QUERY:  SELECT ($1-$2)/$1+$2+0.01)::double precision
********** Error **********
ERROR: error de sintaxis en o cerca de «)»**

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your brackets are misplaced:

('[rast1.val]-[rast2.val])/[rast1.val]+[rast2.val]+0.01' : in that expression you have a closing bracket at -[rast2.val]) that match no opening bracket.

Secondly: Why do you have consecutive brackets there. You shouldn't, thought that won't be breaking anything (('[rast1.val]-[rast2.val])/[rast1.val]+[rast2.val]+0.01'))

Good luck

Fabien

Comment: Thank you Fabien....One of the parentheses was not necessary...